# Object property doesn't change

Tags: php, static

I have come across this problem when plaing with OOP. In this example my intension is to create a gym member with a name and and a weight, who works out for specific time and then loses weight. Unfortunetely the weight object does not update after working out.

When I `var_dump()` gym member object after working out the weight is still 78 even though it meets the criteria to lose weight.

Here is the code:

WEIGHT CLASS:

```
class Weight
{
  protected $weight;

  public function __construct($weight)
  {
    $this->weight = $weight;
  }

  public function gain($kilograms)
  {
    return new static($this->weight + $kilograms);
  }


  public function loose($kilograms)
  {
    return new static($this->weight - $kilograms);
  }


}
```

GYM MEMBER CLASS:

```
class GymMember
{
  protected $name;
  protected $weight;


  public function __construct($name, Weight $weight)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->weight = $weight;
  }


  public function workoutFor(TimeLength $length)
  {

    if(!$length->inSeconds() > (40 * 60 ))
    {
      return 'Keep up the good work!';
    }

    $this->weight->loose(2);

  }

}
```

NEW MEMBER WORKING OUT:

```
$gymMember = new GymMember('MTROBERT', new Weight(78));

$gymMember->workOutFor(Timelength::minutes(45));



var_dump($gymMember);
```

Comment: it should be $this->weight -= $kilograms and not $this->weight - $kilograms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "lose" and "gain" methods are returning a new `Weight` object, but your `GymMember` is not doing anything with that:

```
public function workoutFor(TimeLength $length)
  {

    // ...

    $this->weight->loose(2);

  }
```

Since the lose (tangentially: "**lose**", not "**loose**") method returns a new object instead of modifying itself, and you are not assigning that return value to anything, it's simply lost.

Two possible solutions:

Change `GymMember::workout()` so it does something like:

```
$this->weight = $this->weight->loose(2);
```

Or change `Weight::lose()` so it does something:

```
public function lose($kilograms)
{
   $this->weight -= $kilograms;
}
```

Either of those should fix your problem.

Comment: I have one more question. Why this '=' sign changes that much?? Since loose is supposed to return new weight object with a new weight passed as an argument I thought when running loose() on weight object within gym member class will replace old weight object with new weight object. In the end, loose() returns new objects. I am kind of confused.